# How to include a custom Django Field in my HTML template

Tags: html, django

I'm using a custom Field for my Django project. The code is not mine, a co-worker sent it to me. It's a map to choose a location, the original code is here: https://github.com/Simon-the-Shark/django-mapbox-location-field

I'm fairly new, and don't know how to include that custom Field in my template. The way I know (and the example on that web page) is when using the whole form as a representation of the model, but I want to use the Mapbox Location Field in a template that's not just the form of the model. I want to include this Field in a small form in a popup, and I guess what I don't know is the HTML syntax to include the Field in a simple way such as this:

```
<form method="post" id="form_new_order">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Address:</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="address_input" name="address_input"
                                      class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    # INCLUDE MAPBOX HERE

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Total:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="total_input" name="total_input">
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="mb-sm btn btn-primary" id="enviar_form"> Aceptar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show your forms.py please

Comment: For this view, I'm not using any forms. I have CRUDs for other models, but not for this template, there's no forms.py in the app which contains this template.